# How to enable mtod and ascii art at ssh login?

Tags: ssh, ascii

I am running a ubuntu bionic beaver server on my 12 year old dell dimension e520 desktop as a media and file server.

I use Juicessh android ssh client or putty on Windows to to connect to it and it works.

Though there is one thing I want to enable to make working on it more personalized and that is to have acii art at startup along with a login message aka mtod.

I have looked up some guides online but most of them are insanely oudated or I don't understand what to do.

I was thinking on putting an ascii of Strawhat Luffy from the anime and manga called One piece when I login to ssh.

Currently when I log onto ssh using Juicessh on my android device it displays nothing and I find that pretty boring.

If it could display some useful info at startup such as hard disk space and computer temperature that would be useful too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print MOTD to the user after succesful login, then edit `/etc/motd`

```
sudo editor /etc/motd
```

If you want to print anything before, use SSHD Banner option.

Edit your SSHD config file:

```
sudo editor /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And add this:

```
Banner /etc/issue.net
```

Then you can define your Banner on login prompt in `/etc/issue.net`

```
sudo editor /etc/issue.net
```

This way your message will be visible before authorization.

Comment: Motd is not working for me and I created the file because it did not exist. Restarting my ssh client I don't get the message